# Reader (or Writer) does not handle lines/shapes

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am working on a project where I need to use Excel (to read and write) but am facing numerous issues. My source Excel file has lines (shape object) but it seems PHPExcel Reader and/or Writer don't use/handle those lines. Here is how my source file with lines looks:

[image]

And here how it looks when I read (load) then write (save) using PHPExcel:

[image]

So, for alternative I tried to remove those lines on source file and use images (I made single color thin image with black color) to use as lines. On source files it shows exactly as it does on the above source file (so I have not added another image to show that) but on PHPExcel output it shows like this:

[image]

Any help about how I can preserve the lines/shapes in PHPExcel or how to keep image at its original size?

Comment: PHPExcel will handle cell borders, but won't handle graphic elements (other than pictures) like lines and shapes, and anything that it can't handle is discarded. I'd recommend that you use cell borders for these elements instead if this is possible

Comment: @MarkBaker, dear sir, please check my post.. i have already tried to use the image/picture but it (PHPExcel) change the picture formating (width to 900% :( )